# Scala RDD matching with similar wording

Tags: scala, rdd

So I have a list of verbs

Assuming:

verbs.txt

```
have, have, having, had
give, give, gave, given
take, take, took, taken
```

Splitted them into rdds

```
val verbs = sc.textFile("verbs.txt").map(x => x.split("\n").collect()
```

Therefore,

```
verbs: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(have, have, having, had), Array(give, give, gave, given), Array(take, take, took, taken))
```

Assuming:

```
val wordcount = sc.textFile("data.txt")
```

data.txt

```
have have have having having had had had had had give give give give give give give give give give gave gave given given given given take take took took took took took took taken taken
```

I've calculated the wordcount and therefore
wordcount =

```
(have, 3)
(having, 2)
(had, 5)
(give, 10)
(gave, 2)
(given, 4)
(take, 2)
(took, 6)
(taken, 2)
```

I want to be able to merge the data together with the same verbs
Example: `(have,3),(having,2),(had,5) => (have, 10)`

To return the base form of the verb using the first value of the array.
How am I able to do that?

Comment: It would be nice if you can groupBy the stem  of each word...

Comment: How do u do that? And groupBy which word?

Comment: What is the format of your verb. txt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tag your question as RDD, I am assuming your word count data is a RDD.

```
  // Read text file
  val sc = spark.sparkContext
  val textFile: RDD[String] = sc.textFile("data.txt")

  // So you have this as you said
  val verbs = Array(Array("have", "have", "having", "had"), Array("give", "give", "gave", "given"), Array("take", "take", "took", "taken"))

  val data= textFile
    .flatMap(_.split(" ")) // Split each line to words/tokens its called tokenization (I used backspace as seperator if you have tabs as seperator use that)
    .map(t => (t, 1)) // Generate count per token (i.e. (have, 1))
    .reduceByKey(_ + _) // Count appearance of each token (i.e. (have, 5)


  val t = data.map(d => (verbs.find(v => v.contains(d._1)).map(_.head).getOrElse(d._1), d._2)) // Generates RDD of (optional base verb, count for that verb) e.g (having, 5) => (have, 5), unknown verbs left as it is
    .reduceByKey(_ + _) // Sum all values that having same base verb (have, 5), (have, 3) => (have, 8)

  t.take(10).foreach(println)
```

**Other Option (Without collecting verbs)**

```
  // You dont have to collect this If you want
  val verbs2 = sc.parallelize(Array(Array("have", "have", "having", "had"), Array("give", "give", "gave", "given"), Array("take", "take", "took", "taken"))) // This is the state before collect
    .flatMap(v => v.map(v2 => (v2, v.head))) // This generates tuples of verb -> base verb (e.g had -> have)
    .reduceByKey((k1, k2) => if (k1 == k2) k1 else k2) // Current verbs array generates (have -> have twice, this eliminates duplicate records)

  val data2 = textFile
    .flatMap(_.split(" ")) // Split each line to words/tokens its called tokenization (I used backspace as seperator if you have tabs as seperator use that)
    .map(t => (t, 1)) // Generate count per token (i.e. (have, 1))
    .reduceByKey(_ + _) // Count appearance of each token (i.e. (have, 5)

  val t2 = verbs2.join(data2) // This will join two RDD by their keys (verbs -> (base verb, verb count))
    .map(d => d._2) // This is what we need key is base verb, value is count of that verb
    .reduceByKey(_ + _) // Sum all values that having same base verb (have, 5), (have, 3) => (have, 8)

  t2.take(10).foreach(println)
```

Of course this answer assumes you will always have your verbs array and first element is the base form. If you want something that works without a verbs array and convert any verb to base format that is actually a NLP (Natural Language Processing) task and you need to use some kind of word normalization technique like [this](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html) (As EmiCareOfCell44 indicated). You can also find implementation of such procedures in spark ML library.

Comment: I tried using your method however, I've got (none, 36) instead.

Comment: Did you get none or Unknown? That is strange though you may have a different structure than my example code (That is my only guess). However, souma-kole's answer is more efficient and sparky.

Comment: Could you tell me what I should do if I get the data through sc.textFile("data.txt") instead?

Comment: What is the content of data.txt file?

Comment: @JoshSoh Okay I edited my response, made it more efficent and spark-like. Both options should work for your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to broadcast the forms of verb and then do lookup on that. It will make the lookup easy and performant making the values available in executors in single step.

```
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("Demo")
      .setMaster("local[2]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val verbs = Array(Array("have", "have", "having", "had"), Array("give", "give", "gave", "given"), Array("take", "take", "took", "taken"))
    //brodcast it as a map
    val verbMap = verbs.flatMap(e => {
      e.map(i => i -> e(0))
    }).toMap
    val bdVerbMap = sc.broadcast(verbMap)

    val data = sc.parallelize(List(("have", 3),
      ("having", 2),
      ("had", 5),
      ("give", 10),
      ("gave", 2),
      ("given", 4),
      ("take", 2),
      ("took", 6),
      ("taken", 2)))

    //Lokkup the broadcast values to map every forms of verb then reduce by key
    val unifiedVerbCnt = data.map(t => (bdVerbMap.value.getOrElse(t._1, t._1), t._2))
      .reduceByKey((x, y) => x+y)

    unifiedVerbCnt.collect.foreach(println)
```

Comment: So for the verbs and data I actually got it from an verb. txt and data.txt, so instead of sc.parallelize(), I used sc.textFile("data.txt") however when I run your method I didn't get the result I wanted as it doesn't have a string bracket (having, 2) instead of ("having", 2). What should I do?

Comment: Need to see few lines from both of the files. You need to add that in your original questions (not in comments, here you can't maintain proper format).

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like:

```
verbs
.flatten // will give single array combining all array
.map(p => (p, 1)) // Array( (have, 1), (given, 1))
.groupBy(_._1) // Map(have -> Array((have,1), (have,1)), given -> Array((given,1)))
.map(l => (l._1, l._2.map(_._2).sum)) //Map(have -> 2, given -> 1, had -> 1, took -> 1)
```

Better to try that code in scala shell or IDE tool to understand.